# Correct spelling for BOD and DO

Tags: capitalization, writing-style, acronyms, biology

What is the correct way to spell "biochemical oxygen demand" and "dissolved oxygen" in the middle of a sentence? Should the initial letters be capitalized?

Comment: I'm guessing that the technical field of study that this query is coming from is [Aquatic Biology](http://www.bemidjistate.edu/academics/departments/biology/aquatic/), but that is only a guess. Presumably you know; and, knowing that, and being sufficiently involved in that field to ask such a sophisticated question, you really *should* know which style manual is authoritative in that field, and where to get a-hold of it and how to use it.

Comment: Yes. At least until they acquire an official status of an acronym, like *laser* today. "BOD is similar in function to chemical oxygen demand (COD) ..." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemical_oxygen_demand

Comment: @BrianDonovan Why guess? What's Google for? :) Anaerobic digestion; Environmental science; Water quality indicators

Comment: What is the middle of the sentence in the middle of? If it's a departmental publication, or a journal article, the answer may be found in the style guidelines of the department or journal.

Comment: I don’t know why you think that they would be capitalized when used as separate words.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know whether the fact that the initialisms "BOD" and "OD" are spelled in all caps has a carryover effect requiring the spelled-out terms to be initial-capped (that is, to be rendered in the middle of regular text as "Biochemical Oxygen Demand" and "Dissolved Oxygen").

I have never seen a style guide that endorsed such a carryover effect, so I believe that the answer in your case is probably no: Even in the presence of "BOD" and "OD," you would normally spell "biochemical oxygen demand" and "dissolved oxygen" in all-lowercase letters, just as you would if you never used "BOD" and "OD" in your paper at all. Of course, style guides sometimes embrace the oddest decisions, and you should certainly consult the one that your institution or publisher uses, to make sure that it isn't the weird exception.